# Count the number of terminated processes started by the specified user

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I need to count the number of terminated processes launched by the specified user in Ubuntu. But I don’t know exactly which command to use and which keys to use. I assume ps is suitable here, but specifically which keys to use and how to implement this in a script file?

Comment: Am I groking this correct? You want number of processes started by user - number of this users processes still running. Why?

Comment: `ps` only tells you about one moment in time. It does not tell you the history of started and terminated processes. You could conceivably use `ps` to frequently poll the running processes and then infer when those of a given user are terminated, but this would be at best an approximation.

Comment: Maybe process accounting? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468909/what-does-process-accounting-mean-in-linux