# How do I insert my own lib to other binaries in Linux?

Tags: command-line, c, system-calls, glibc, exec

My goal is developing a tool for educational purposes which logs commands on a system. Until now have found primitive ways to do this but all these ways can be easily bypassed so I had this idea to intercept commands right away and I was introduced into `LD_PRELOADING`.

I successfully made a working C code where I could intercept commands executed from a C program using `execve` but I'm wondering how can I make this in global level.

Thank You guys, I'd be pretty happy to hear something from you!

Comment: When you say "in global level", do you mean with root access? With root access, things like the audit subsystem come into play. The audit subsystem could easily log all uses of the `execve()` and related system calls for all users, if you wanted (and had the disk space for the resulting log). If you have only regular user access, `LD_PRELOAD` might be about the best you can do generally.

Comment: Now that I have found how to intercept a command executed from a C program which calls `execve()` I wanna do for every command executed or called from user’s space terminal

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer in the man pages of [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

> ```
>           There are various methods of specifying libraries to be
>           preloaded, and these are handled in the following order:
>
>           (1) The LD_PRELOAD environment variable.
>
>           (2) The --preload command-line option when invoking the
>               dynamic linker directly.
>
>           (3) The /etc/ld.so.preload file (described below).
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    /etc/ld.so.preload
>           File containing a whitespace-separated list of ELF shared
>           objects to be loaded before the program.  See the
>           discussion of LD_PRELOAD above.  If both LD_PRELOAD and
>           /etc/ld.so.preload are employed, the libraries specified
>           by LD_PRELOAD are preloaded first.  /etc/ld.so.preload has
>           a system-wide effect, causing the specified libraries to
>           be preloaded for all programs that are executed on the
>           system.  (This is usually undesirable, and is typically
>           employed only as an emergency remedy, for example, as a
>           temporary workaround to a library misconfiguration issue.)
> ```

By the way, Linux kernel already has a [Process Accounting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468909/what-does-process-accounting-mean-in-linux) capability that can log every process that runs on the system. The only downside of this capability is that it only logs the process name, and not the full command line and arguments.

If you do need the full command line arguments, you could use the [auditd](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-linux-auditing-auditd) framework, and configure rules for `execve` systemcall.

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64-S execve -k all-commands
```

And then you could use the `ausearch` tool to check all the commands that ran on the system.